# Trouble referencing appCompat in my project on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries, android-appcompat

So I have just started running through the tutorial located [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Even though it starts off easily enough, with everything being described, the second chapter rushes you through action bars.

I have managed to import appCompat; which was located at `C:\Users\New\Desktop\Programmin' languages\Android dev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\eclipse\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat` -  for me.
After importing appCompat I referenced it by going to properties>android and then the adding it to libraries.

What is confusing me is that the compiler allows me to write

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

without any errors; though I have referenced

```
android:support:v7:app:ActionBarActivity
```

so I didn't think that would give me an error.

Errors are coming from things like action_search (which I'll assume is a referenced xml) and openSearch() (a referenced class) - in my java activities

and @drawable/tab_unselected  -   which is located in my drawable-hdpi (under res).

I'm assuming that the person who wrote the tutorial presumed that my project would get these resources from the appCompat directory, but for some reason it isn't.

Please help, because the next chapter just goes on to describe how to develop new things - without addressing issues that could arise first.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799478/appcompat-library-for-android-how-its-linked-with-project/22799866#22799866) on how to properly include the appcompat libraries in your Android project.