# Appcompat library for android - how it's linked with project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

In which way is android appcompat library linked with a project (where in code is that connection visible)? I tried to rename it just to see what's gonna happen and my project gave me errors everywhere...

Also, is it possible to somehow use only one appcompat library for all projects?

Comment: The method to link Java external libraries, Android included, has been the same since day one. What have you tried? And what problem did you get with the linked libraries?

Comment: So, I created a project and, since I obviously can't have one appcompat library for multiple projects, tried to rename it in something similar to project name

And then Eclipse gave me errors... I tried to configure build path in some way (I was doing some similar stuff before) but I failed miserably :)

Comment: You CAN have one appcompat library for multiple Android projects. See my answer below for linking external Java libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse, to share the appcompat libraries across multiple Android projects, do the following:

1. In Eclipse, select **File | Import | Existing Projects into workspace**. click **Next**.
2. Click **Browse**, and browse to the directory of Android appcompat directory. The default directory should be: `..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\`.
3. Click **Finish** to add the new project.
4. Select the **Properties** tab of an Android project.
5. In the **Properties** screen, select the **Android** option (on the left pane), then click **Add**, and select the appcompat library from the list.
6. Click **OK** to save the changes.

Note: Repeat the above steps if you want to add other shared libraries into your Android projects.

Whereas to *embed* the appcompat libraries in each of your Android project, just copy the JAR files from the appcompat's **libs** folder into your project's **libs** folder.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help you understand Android a bit more. ;)