# Why can't I import google play services into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I am trying to import the `google-play-services_lib` into `Eclipse` but I am not able to import it as I am getting the following warning `no projects are found to import`. Can anyone suggest a solution to this? Please give step by step instructions as I am a newbie.

Comment: Select "Import-Existing Android code into Workspace". You must be clicking "Existing Projects into Workspace"

Comment: Copy `google-play-services_lib` into `workspace` and then import into Eclipse with uncheck an option of copy into work space..

Comment: The above solution is useful as well.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799478/appcompat-library-for-android-how-its-linked-with-project/22799866#22799866). Even though it's for another library, but the steps to import external libraries are the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can import android project in two ways,

> [image]

In your case I suggest you to use 2nd way.

Note, the Android project which doesnt contain `.class` file, `.project` file can be import using 2nd option. In all other cases 1st option is better.

Comment: For me the second way shows not projects in the list view. The first way does but the process of importing fails with a null pointer exception. Gaah updates!! I knew I should not have updated the Android SDK, it broke everything.

Answer (score 1):

Delete project (google_play_services) from SDK Manager then reinstall project  (google_play_services) and import.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose option to 'Create project from existing source' from File->New->Android Project