# Using features of an android library

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded a library to use in my android application and I added it to my eclipse workspace as a project. After I marked it as a library in the project's properties, I added the library to my app project, but still, I can't access the features of the libraries. Is there something to do before you can start using a library after adding it to a project?

Comment: try to clean the project. btw, have you added from build n configure?

Comment: I already tried cleaning the project, and I added the library by adding it in the project properties

Comment: @MartinHoffmann: Have a look at my answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799478/appcompat-library-for-android-how-its-linked-with-project/22799866#22799866) to see if it helps. Maybe you're missing a step. Note: You may need to remove your recent import and try again with my suggession.

Answer (score -1):

is it a jar? Can you see .jar in lib folder ? you can try this:

your prokects- properties - java build path - Add External JARs - select the jar - (keep it in lib folder)

Comment: It's not a jar, it came as a folder